# Import .sql file to a specific schema (not in public schema) PostgreSQL 12

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

```sh
sudo psql -f sample-schema.sql -U postgres -p 5432 -h my ipaddress -d dbname
```

How to specify into what schema the data go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the SQL statements in the script are not schema qualified, you can set the search path:

```sh
psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h my ipaddress -d dbname \
  -c 'SET search_path = target_schema' -f sample-schema.sql
```

If the SQL statements in the script are qualified with the `public` schema, there is little you can do. You could temporarily rename the `public` schema, execute the script, then rename the schemas again.